# Multiple groups of items with checkable state uncheck each other

Tags: android, user-interface, checkbox

I have three groups of menu items that are checkable.
Each group is configured with single checkable behavior, but checking an item in group A will uncheck items in group B and C.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add unique IDs to each of the group items in the xml file.

```
   <group
        android:id="@+id/menuGroup_1"           
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/group_1_item_1"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/group_1_item_2"/>
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/menuGroup_2"       
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/group_2_item_1"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/group_2_item_2"/>
    </group>
```

Then implement your logic here:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.group_1_item_1:
            item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.group_1_item_2:
            item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.group_2_item_1:
            item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.group_2_item_2:
            item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Hm, this is the same i have except the code

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        return true;
    }

Should be enough in this case, or?